# dqrng with Rcpp for drawing from a normal and a binomial distribution

Tags: rcpp

I'm trying to learn how to draw random numbers from a normal and a binomial distribution from within a Rcpp OpenMP loop.

I wrote the following code using `R::rnorm` and `R::rbinom` which I understand to be a be a [don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54717911/1800784).

```r
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <dqrng.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(dqrng)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat  my_matrix3(const arma::mat& A, 
                      const arma::mat& B) {

  dqrng::dqRNGkind("Xoroshiro128+");
  dqrng::dqset_seed(42);



  const int nObservations = A.n_cols;
  const int nDraws = B.n_rows;
  const int nRows = nObservations * nDraws;

  // Show initialization information
  Rcpp::Rcout << "nObservations: " << nObservations << std::endl 
              << "nDraws: " << nDraws << std::endl 
              << "nRows: " << nRows << std::endl;

  arma::mat out(nRows, 5);

  // Show trace of matrix construction
  Rcpp::Rcout << "out - rows: " << out.n_rows << std::endl 
              << "out - columns: " << out.n_cols << std::endl;

  int i,n,iter,row;
  double dot_product, random_number, p;
  omp_set_num_threads(2);
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, n, iter, row)
  for(i = 0; i < nDraws; ++i){
    for(n = 0; n < nObservations; ++n) {
      row = i * nObservations + n;
      dot_product = arma::as_scalar(A.col(n).t() * B.row(i).t());
      // Show trace statement of index being accessed
      out(row, 0) = i + 1;
      out(row, 1) = n + 1;
      out(row, 2) = R::rnorm(2.0, 1.0) ;//dqrng::dqrnorm(1, 2.0, 1.0)[1]; 
      out(row, 3) = 1 / (1 + std::exp(-out(row, 3) - std::exp(dot_product)));
      out(row, 4) = R::rbinom(1,out(row, 3));
    }
  }

  return out;
}

/*** R
set.seed(9782)
A <- matrix(rnorm(10), nrow = 5)
B <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 5)
test <- my_matrix3(A = A, B = B)
test

mean(test[,5])
*/
```

As suggested by @ralf-stubner I'm trying to replace that code with [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dqrng/vignettes/dqrng.html). If I understood the documentation correctly, I can replace `R::rnorm(2.0, 1.0)` with `dqrng::dqrnorm(1, 2.0, 1.0)[1]`. Is that right? What about replacing `R::rbinom(1,out(row, 3))`? I was not able to find any reference to drawing from a binomial in [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dqrng/dqrng.pdf)

---

I was able to write the following code that draws from a binomial distribution in parallel:

```r
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(dqrng, BH, RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <pcg_random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/binomial_distribution.hpp>
#include <xoshiro.h>
#include <dqrng_distribution.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat parallel_random_matrix(int n, int m, int ncores, double p=0.5) {
  //dqrng::uniform_distribution dist(0.0, 1.0);
  boost::random::binomial_distribution<int> dist(1,p);
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng(42);
  arma::mat out(n,m);
  // ok to use rng here



#pragma omp parallel num_threads(ncores)
{
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus lrng(rng);      // make thread local copy of rng 
  lrng.jump(omp_get_thread_num() + 1);  // advance rng by 1 ... ncores jumps 
  auto gen = std::bind(dist, std::ref(lrng));

#pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    double lres(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      out(j,i) = gen(); /// CAN I MAKE P BE A FUNCTION OF i and j? how???
    }
  }
}
// ok to use rng here
return out;
}

/*** R
parallel_random_matrix(5, 5, 4, 0.75)
*/

> parallel_random_matrix(5, 5, 4, 0.75)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1    1    1
[3,]    0    1    0    1    0
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Is there a way to call `out(j,i) = gen();` and make the probability be a function of i and j??

Is there anything wrong with the code I wrote?

Comment: Please see the [parallel RNG usage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dqrng/vignettes/parallel.html) vignette for details. Currently the R and C++ interfaces are not meant for parallel usage. You have to use the provided generators directly. For the binomial distribution you can use the one from boost (via BH package).

Comment: Thanks for the help @RalfStubner. I think I was able to figure out how to do the hard part. My question now is how to make `p` in `gen` be a function of i and j. For example, I tried things like setting `gen(p=0.0002)` but it does not work as I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create a new distribution object within the loop:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(dqrng, BH, RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <boost/random/binomial_distribution.hpp>
#include <xoshiro.h>
#include <dqrng_distribution.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat parallel_random_matrix(int n, int m, int ncores, double p=0.5) {
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng(42);
  arma::mat out(n,m);
  // ok to use rng here

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(ncores)
{
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus lrng(rng);      // make thread local copy of rng 
  lrng.jump(omp_get_thread_num() + 1);  // advance rng by 1 ... ncores jumps 

#pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      // p can be a function of i and j
      boost::random::binomial_distribution<int> dist(1,p);
      auto gen = std::bind(dist, std::ref(lrng));
      out(j,i) = gen();
    }
  }
}
  // ok to use rng here
  return out;
}

/*** R
parallel_random_matrix(5, 5, 4, 0.75)
*/
```

This way you can make `p` depend on `i` and `j`. It might be more efficient to keep one global `dist` object and reconfigure it within the loop, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268049/how-to-set-the-parameters-of-boostuniform-int-distribution-outside-of-the-stan) for a similar question.

Comment: One final question. In my original question I mentioned that I actually want to draw from a binomial and a normal. Do I need to have multiple `lrng`? One for each `gen` function? For example, if I have 1 binomial and 2 normals (with different means) would I need 3 `lrng`?

Comment: @Ignacio No, you can `bind` a single `lrng` to multiple distributions. BTW, please open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/daqana/dqrng) if you have suggestions how to improve the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @ralf-stubner. I will post an idea for an additional example as soon as I get it to work :-)