# Inconsistent results between dqrng and R API for PRNG in RCPP

Tags: r, random, rcpp, rcppparallel

I am attempting to implement a particle filter within Rcpp and use OpenMP to parallelise the transition step. I am using `dqrng` to create threadsafe RNG with using the `boost` distribution functions as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724317/dqrng-with-rcpp-for-drawing-from-a-normal-and-a-binomial-distribution).

The code for the R API can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alessio-b-zak/fb683caa2179bdd87ed224a68dd0ee3b) and introducing `dqrng` [here](https://gist.github.com/alessio-b-zak/83719890ff404e5b65e50256bfcd7f9d)

The issue I am having is that, using the R API, I achieve correct results, verified against alternate implementations, with the density of the estimator being roughly normally distributed as expected. However, for the `dqrng` version the density of the estimator does not appear correct with differing results being obtained. The density plots can be seen below.

[image: Density of estimator with dqrng]

[image: Density of estimator with R API]

Does anyone have any understanding of why this might be the case?

Comment: Different (and I may add _entirely different_) generators, different results.  The most likely (but I am guessing here) answer may be that you are doing something wrong with `dqrng`.

Comment: Indeed they are different generators but there is a significantly large difference in results which I do not believe should be present. I agree that the issue is almost definitely with the usage of `dqrng` but I cannot see a substantial difference from the linked example and was hoping someone more familiar with the library could spot the error.

Comment: Can you reduce the two code examples? This is quite for from a [mre].

Comment: From a quick look at the code I have the impression you are trying to change two things at the same time: Introduce `dqrng` and OpenMP. For the latter, you have switched from `Rcpp` to `RcppParallel` data structures. I would suggest to use a more step wise approach: Use your working code and only change it to `dqrng`. If that works, switch to `RcppParallel` data structures. Only in the end go to OpenMP.